# Optionally required parameters in typescript

Tags: typescript, function, vue.js, redux, vuex

I am trying to strongly type a flux implementation (Vuex, to be more specific). My current code looks like this:

```
const actions = {
  first(context: Context, payload: string) { return doSomething(context, payload); },
  second(context: Context) { return doSomethingWithNoPayload(context); }
}

type Actions = typeof actions;
type PayloadType<A extends keyof Actions> = Parameters<Actions[A]>[1];

function dispatch<A extends keyof Actions>(action: A): ReturnType<Actions[A]>;
function dispatch<A extends keyof Actions>(action: A, payload: Payload<A>): ReturnType<Actions[A]>;
function dispatch<A extends keyof Actions>(action: A, payload: Payload<A> = undefined): Promise<any> {
  return Promise.resolve({ action, payload });
}
```

What I am trying to accomplish is:

```
dispatch("first") // error, no payload specified
dispatch("first", false) // error, payload type is not correct
dispatch("first", "correct") // ok, payload type is correct

dispatch("second", "something") // error, shouldn't pass payload`
dispatch("second") // ok, payload is not passed
dispatch("third") // error, non-existent action
```

But using an optional parameter as the payload is not enforcing me to pass the payload to the "first" action that actually needs a payload. If I don't declare the payload as optional, then I'm forced to call `dispatch("second", undefined)` because now I need to pass 2 parameters.

Any thoughts? Much appreciated.

Comment: Please consider editing the code here to constitute a [mcve] so that the only issue someone sees when dropping it into an IDE is the issue you are facing.  As it stands there are undeclared types, thereby raising the barrier to entry for answering this question.  We have to guess definitions for `doSomething()`, `Payload`, `Context`, etc before we can even begin to reproduce your problem.  My suggestion without reproducible code is either to manually specify the string literals in your overloads, or to start using tuple types for parameters and do more complex type manipulation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I'd proceed assuming you need the compiler to determine the `dispatch()` signature programmatically from the type of `actions`.  First, in order to get your example to compile I will guess some types, which hopefully don't affect the correctness of the solution:

```
// who knows
type Context = { c: string };
declare function doSomething(c: Context, payload: string): number;
declare function doSomethingWithNoPayload(c: Context): boolean;

const actions = {
  first(context: Context, payload: string) { return doSomething(context, payload); },
  second(context: Context) { return doSomethingWithNoPayload(context); }
}

type Actions = typeof actions;
```

TypeScript 3.0 introduced [support for using tuples to represent function parameter lists](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions).  This gives us the `Parameters<FuncType>` type alias that returns a tuple, as you're using.  But it also gives us more ability to manipulate tuples in general.  Here we define `Tail<T>`, which takes a tuple type `T` and returns a new tuple with the first element removed:

```
// strip the first element off a tuple
// e.g., Tail<[1,2,3]> is [2,3]
type Tail<T extends readonly any[]> =
  ((...t: T) => void) extends ((h: any, ...r: infer R) => void) ? R : never;
```

Then we can make a single signature for `dispatch()` which takes one argument of type `A`, and a rest parameter of type `Tail<Parameters<Actions[A]>>`.

```
// use rest tuples
declare function dispatch<A extends keyof Actions>(
  action: A, ...payload: Tail<Parameters<Actions[A]>>
): ReturnType<Actions[A]>;
```

This should give you exactly the behavior you want:

```
dispatch("first") // error, no payload specified
dispatch("first", false) // error, payload type is not correct
dispatch("first", "correct") // ok, payload type is correct

dispatch("second", "something") // error, shouldn't pass payload`
dispatch("second") // ok, payload is not passed
dispatch("third") // error, non-existent action
```

Looks good.  Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/PTAEHcAsHtQawHbXAZwFABcCeAHApqAMLQIZ4AeGoAvKAN6gDGAXKChgE4CWCA5qAF8A3GgAmeRgBsAhhwIAzAK4JGGLiVCjoAZWgBbPBkg9eAChZESZSgBpQOaVknRpo1u258AlKwSK9AEZ4HCLiUrIKyqrqCJo6+obGfADqXEYActAACo7OruasxKQUGD6gAdDQknjSCCJojCTsoNLRTTT0aKCg8lwc7OZWJYVDtva5Lm5snCZe9KByGIocsVq6BkYmg8VjDk6TXkKCNl1sEiSi29YYIzul84vLq-EbSbypGdkT+Y13h4JoARoTC4AgAQTaCBQHWw+Gg8hakJQ9RA024OFARgUfWaeGqBlIoHhCOkmMUOGqaFReAAdLwaXYACrSLiSAA8AG0AIw2ABMNgAzABdAB8oC40I5-OFIPwoGZrLZjNAJTwCFE0LkrhIkiwLQQWA5opop1MphpFpu8rm1DFADdoFxRHNVeroWbIKxalg7BaaRxWDx5MFQAAlG32x3O0AAfjDoF8eDtwRRYEUKAIcmaSwpeHQYRkch6UTUGlEEocGEYkDZYJVlDVGvgeCw8NAENLUJFplOrU7rDBvotezyUwV7JyHGkG2CKFrSI5YNFIrQZVDhiejNB887KEXovq5ZQlerpgARL1+hgz3NqRwONAOHYkON9q42PhGFxenhRGIK9IVaQOel7sGedjyNIkgZreYDBA+T6vqOmKguK0JIFQjT3hIGD-segGnheOLXnYZ5YXIqg3qAqLQHAdgjpMKFyhKTCPhRuF4SewFnhmvyiOBoA8Qkmx8FRd4IXYKAwIokiiAgADkVAOCg0IMa4AAGnEEdxvEXGJYC0fR3yiGhoAYeMKm-lpQHnpsHD8bBKr3o+z4kAAtBQEpkISfYxEAA)

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks for your contribution! I didn't put the types because I thought they would not be important for the solution.